# How do I find the first and last day of the previous month using SQL?

Tags: sql, date

I am using IBM Data Studio to access data on an AS400, I cannot figure out how to programmatically find the first and last date of the previous month to use in an BETWEEN clause. For example, if I ran it today it would return 20211201 and 20211231. I have done some other date math in the past but this one is beyond me. Below is an example of a date function I have used successfully in this version of SQL.

```
{DEC(DATE(DAYS((CURRENT_DATE) - 15 DAY)))}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
DATE(YEAR(CURRENT_DATE)||'-'||MONTH(CURRENT_DATE)||'-1') - 1 MONTH
```

and

```
DATE(YEAR(CURRENT_DATE)||'-'||MONTH(CURRENT_DATE)||'-1') - 1 DAY
```

Comment: Is there a way to return the date in the format YYYYMMDD, so 20211231 instead of 2021-12-31?